# Andengine TimerHandler and detecting collisions

Tags: java, android, andengine

I'm developing a game where LittleMan can move from block to block, and certain blocks are moving. I'm trying to detect when he moves to a new moving block, if that block is beneath him or if it has moved. I'm using Andengine's `TimerHandler` to check every 0.1 seconds but it is not working. Here's the code:

```
private void OnMovingBlock(final int CurrentPosRow, final int CurrentPosColumn) {
    this.getEngine().registerUpdateHandler(new TimerHandler(0.1f, true, new ITimerCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onTimePassed(final TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {
            if (LittleManPos[0] == CurrentPosRow && LittleManPos[1] == CurrentPosColumn) {
                if (!LittleMan.collidesWith(MapRectangles[CurrentPosRow][CurrentPosColumn])) {

                    RestartScene();

                }
            }
        }
    }));

}
```

It seems he can move to the block and sit there with it moving in and out beneath him but it doesn't call `RestartScene()` UNTIL I move him again. Any idea where I am going wrong? Or is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't create a `Timer`?

```
TimerTask task = new TimerTask(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        // your code goes here
    }
};

Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.sechedule(task, 0, 100); // 100 --> 0.1 second
```

To cancel the `Timer`, call `timer.cancel();`.

Comment: Thank you, this helps a lot! I would upvote your comment but it tells me I am too new, sorry =/ I'm hoping I can impose another question on the code you provided: Is there was way to use timer.cancel() WITHIN the run method? Such as in my original code within if statements, if a condition is matched, then I can cancel the timer? Much thanks!